# Laravel BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist When Trying to Checkout

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to save products from cart to db (checkout), but get *BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::save does not exist* instead.
Here's the code.

**Controller**

```html
public function checkout(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'phonenumber' => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:8',
            'country' => 'required|string',
            'city' => 'required|string',
            'address' => 'required',
            'zipcode' => 'required|digits:5',
            'creditcardnumber' => 'required|digits:16',
            'expiremonth' => 'required|digits:2',
            'expireyear' => 'required|digits:2',
            'cvc' => 'required|digits:3',
        ]);

        if(!Session::has('cart')){
            return view('cart.index');
        }
        $oldCart = Session::get('cart');
        $cart = new Cart($oldCart);

        foreach ($cart->items as $order) {
            Product::where('id',$order['product_id'])
                    ->decrement('quantity');
        }


        $order = new Order();
        $order->cart = serialize($cart);
        $order->address = $request->input('address');
        $order->name = $request->input('name');
        $order->phonenumber = $request->input('phonenumber');
        $order->city = $request->input('city');
        $order->country = $request->input('country');
        $order->zipcode = $request->input('zipcode');

        Auth::user()->orders->save($order); //the error pointed at this

        Session::forget('cart');
        return redirect()->route('home.index')->with('success','Successfully purchased the products!');
    }
}
```

Comment: try this Auth::user()->orders()->save($order)   or Auth::user()->orders()->create($order);  create() method need mass assignment protcted $guarded = [] in order model

Comment: Thank you, it worked with Auth::user()->orders()->save($order). But what's the different with create($order)?

Comment: welcome! laravel provides different method to insert rec in table.. create() one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
Auth::user()->orders->save($order)
```

To this:

```
Auth::user()->orders()->save($order)
```

Reason for this is, if you just call it like `Auth::user()->orders`, Eloquent will run the query and return the collection of orders. Laravel does this in the background, using [magic methods](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) (__get() in this example, to be specific) And, collections don't have the save() method on them.

On the other hand, if you call it like `Auth::user()->orders()`, Eloquent will instead return a query builder object (relationship object), which has the save() method.